# Table, allow one colum to have lots of room, while forcing other columns to be equivalent width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've made the following in HTML/CSS

[image]

The only issue is, I want the **Very Good, Good, Fair, Poor, Very Poor** columns to be equal width while still allowing the "question" column to take up as much space needed if the question happens to be long.

Comment: What have you tried?....  What does your code look like?  What errors are you getting?  What do you not understand?  Show us your code to get help?  The questions could go on forever.  This question needs more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Styling

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
.question_col{
    width: 25%;
}
.answer_col{
    width: 15%;
}
```

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="question_col">Questions</td>
        <td class="answer_col">Very Good</td>  
        <td class="answer_col">Good</td>
        <td class="answer_col">Fair</td>
        <td class="answer_col">Poor</td>
        <td class="answer_col">Very Poor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Questions</td>
        <td>Very Good</td>  
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>Fair</td>
        <td>Poor</td>
        <td>Very Poor</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```